# If you got mine, then I got yours

Tags: riddle

> - It's not good to let me be away, down, off or out. Stand your ground!
> - It's good to let me go up so that when things go down, you can put them up again!
> - If you got mine, then I got yours! All for one and one for all!
> - If you are on me, please get off me, you are not my mom!
> - If you got a problem with me, don't say it to my face, that's just rude!

Who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> A back

```
    It's not good to let me be away, down, off or out. Stand your ground!
```

> "Back away", "back down", "back off" and "back out" are all phrases for retreating—the opposite of standing your ground.

```
    It's good to let me go up so that when things go down, you can put them up again!
```

> Back-up your stuff, so if something catastrophically fails you can bring things back up again by restoring it.  Thanks **@oleslaw** for figuring that one out!

```
    If you got mine, then I got yours! All for one and one for all!
```

> "If you've got my back, I've got yours"—like "all for one and one for all", an expression of solidarity and mutual support.

```
    If you are on me, please get off me, you are not my mom!
```

> Get off my back!

```
    If you got a problem with me, don't say it to my face, that's just rude!
```

> Normally, talking to one's back is rude. But if you're talking to a back, then talking to its face is talking to the back's "back" which would be rude.

Comment: Ahh! That should be it. +1

Comment: I did think this however it was the "Who am I?" that threw me.

Comment: The second line is about importancy of doing backups.

Comment: Good job on finding the last one! Kudos to @oleslaw on finding the missing one too!

Comment: @oleslaw Thanks, I wasn't getting there :)  good one OP!

Comment: I genuinely read the title when it was posted, thought "eh it's probably back" and then never actually read it, assuming that I had been mislead. I regret that xD

Answer (score 1):

Is it - >

> Knowledge

It's not good to let me be away, down, off or out. Stand your ground!

> We should not let the knowledge go away or reduce(down), off or out. We should hold on to it.

It's good to let me go up so that when things go down, you can put them up again!

> It's good to grow it so that when required specially in bad conditions, we can put it up and use it to make the conditions alright.

If you got mine, then I got yours! All for one and one for all!

> Sharing knowledge

If you are on me, please get off me, you are not my mom!

> Not sure about this one. But if I take it literally, if you are sitting on a book or some knowledgeable thing, you should not. It's considered as unethical.

If you got a problem with me, don't say it to my face, that's just rude!

> It's rude to treat knowledge in a bad way. If you have a problem learning, try harder.

Not sure if its anywhere close :) Just wanted to give it a shot